# What (an) exciting news it is!

Tags: grammar

Can I add "an" after “what" in the following sentence ?

> We'll have a summer camp soon.
>
> What (an) exciting news it is!

Comment: As a native speaker, I would say no: 'What an exciting news it is!' simply sounds wrong to me. Don't worry, though, as this kind of sentence construction is very rare. Most sentences are statements, such as 'that car is travelling very fast'. However, some sentences use a particular kind of grammatical syntax to make an exclamation. E.g. 'how fast that car is travelling!'. Again, this is unusual, and if you knew when to use such a sentence, then I would say that your command of English is quite exceptional!

Comment: No. _News_ is an uncountable noun; if you wanted to refer to a particular story you would have to say _piece of news_ or _item of news_

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. 'News' is an uncountable noun. Since it is uncountable we can't say 'a' (one).

Therefore

> What exciting news it is!

is the correct form.

If you need to qualify 'how much news', you need to use 'piece(s) of news'.
In your case, it's correct to say

> What an exciting piece of news (it is)!

Comment: But we can say "this news".

Comment: @StephenLiu Oddly enough, yes you can. :-)

Comment: Indeed! You can use 'this' and 'that' with uncountable nouns. Pretty odd as @PrimeMover says!

Comment: But you don't say "this water" or "that sand". How strange!

Comment: @StephenLiu Indeed you do - all the time:   **This water is for the dog** - **That sand is not suitable for making concrete**

Comment: What do you mean when you say "this water"?

Comment: "This water (that I have in this bowl) *points at bowl* is for the dog, but you can drink that water *points at water bottle*."